# Complex SQL join condition to Eliminate the NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE EMP 
(
    E_ID INT,
    E_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    GENDER VARCHAR(20),
    CONTACT INT,
    AGE INT
);

INSERT INTO EMP 
VALUES (1001, 'ABC', 'MALE', NULL, NULL),
       (1001, 'ABC', NULL, 8989, NULL),
       (1001, 'ABC', NULL, NULL, 28);
```

I tried following query.. But not works..

```
SELECT 
    A.E_ID, B.E_NAME, B.GENDER, B.CONTACT, B.AGE 
FROM 
    EMP AS A 
INNER JOIN 
    ENT AS B ON A.E_ID = B.E_ID 
             AND A.E_NAME = B.E_NAME  
             AND A.GENDER = B.GENDER 
             AND A.CONTACT = A.CONTACT 
WHERE
    A.CONTACT IS NOT NULL;
```

[Employee Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0H8EW.png)

How to get the single row output with not null values?

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caXzh.png)

Comment: E_ID       E_Name Gender contact age
1001 ABC           MALE   8989 28      I am Expecting this output..

Comment: I believe this is the result of a `JOIN`, Isn't it?.. If so, control the `NULL` values while joining.

Comment: Please add the expected output in you question (not in comments)

Comment: Either join, where or subquery.. But in a single row..

Comment: Please post data and code as text not images.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MAX()` will not include `NULLs`. Try this:

```
SELECT 
      e_id, 
      e_name, 
      MAX(gender) as gender, 
      MAX(age) as age, 
      MAX(contact) as contact
FROM employee
GROUP BY e_id, e_name
```

**Note:** If there are more than 1 Non-null values, tweak the code accordingly. Else you might end up in considering wrong one.

Look at the sample output in *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=86434a6e959497d6c4f07489a17823ba)*

Comment: Please consider `accepting` the answer. And `upvote` if it is useful. [Click on the tick mark next to the answer to accept]

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate functions like `max` ignore `null`s, so one possible trick is to group by the `e_id` and `e_name`, and apply `max` to the other columns:

```sql
SELECT   e_id, e_name, MAX(gender), MAX(contact), MAX(age)
FROM     employee
GROUP BY e_id, e_name
```